# Python Sanic ext 22.9.0 - Open API static YAML file loading

Tags: python, openapi, sanic

I am using sanic/sanic-ext 22.9.0 , I need to load a static open api yaml or json file rather than autogenerate so that when I access it as  `<url>/docs`,  the static yaml file is loaded and UI display either Swagger or redoc version of UI with the API definition.
Any suggestion on how to achieve this.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: sanic-ext   has open api decorator for dynamically generating openapi/swagger docs which can be access via `/doc` `/swagger` or `/redocs`.   I used a swagger editor to  write the entire open api  yaml file ,   I need a way to load this into sanic on startup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a few options.

**OPTION 1**

Load your custom OAS into Sanic, and server that.

```py
@app.before_server_start
async def load_oas(app: Sanic):
    custom_oas_dict = load_spec_from_yaml()
    app.ext.openapi.raw(custom_oas_dict)
```

**OPTION 2**

Turn off OAS and roll your own solution, including swagger/redoc, etc

```py
app.config.OAS = False
```

**OPTION 3**

Serve your custom OAS, and overwrite the HTML to point to your custom file.

```py
app.config.OAS_PATH_TO_REDOC_HTML = "/path/to/custom/redoc.html"
app.config.OAS_PATH_TO_SWAGGER_HTML = "/path/to/custom/swagger.html"

app.static("/custom/oas.json", "/path/to/custom/oas.json")
```

Comment: FYI - Just opened this as a feature request for a 4th solution. I will likely implement this for the 22.12 release: https://github.com/sanic-org/sanic-ext/issues/146